# PHP is adding slashes to characters when inserting into MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, security, filtering

When a ' is typed into a text field for example, PHP puts a \ before it.

I'm using the following for filtering:

```
$comment_body = $_POST['comment_body'];
$comment_body = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($comment_body));
$comment_body = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$comment_body);
```

How do I stop this slash from appearing?

Comment: The `mysqli_real_escape_string` function call escapes the single quote  with the backward slash to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: that is what your mysqli_real_escape_string is doing.  It is supposed to be that way

Comment: I know that, but I've used it on other sites and the \ isn't posted into the database. Is there a way I can stop it from been posted or a way to stop it from been displayed with the \ without removing the mysqli_real_escape_string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is what mysqli_real_escape_string does. This should only be used when putting the data into a database. If you are going to output the $comment_body just leave off the last line of the snippet. If you are getting double escaping happening it is probably the result of the  [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) configuration directive.

Comment: I know that, but I've used it on other sites and the \ isn't posted into the database. Is there a way I can stop it from been posted or a way to stop it from been displayed with the \ without removing the mysqli_real_escape_string? I am actually inserting this into the database by the way

Comment: That's what's happened then, the server was updated to the latest version of PHP. Is there a way I can hide the \ when querying out of the database?

Comment: @James ... that wouldn't be it then magic quotes where removed in 5.4

Comment: Actually, my bad, it runs 5.4 @Orangepill

Comment: @james is it possible someone on the site fixed for the absence of magic quotes by doing something like `$_POST = array_map("addslashes", $_POST);`?

Comment: I don't think so! I'm hosting with GoDaddy (not the worlds best I know).

Comment: @James I didn't know if this was a customer site. I've seen people do stuff like that when php version is upgraded and previous code relied on a deprecated/eliminated feature.

Answer (score 1):

You should use sanitization with regards to **context**:

When saving to database use only **mysqli_real_escape_string()**. When outputing varible to HTML then just go with **htmlspecialchars()**.

Automatic adding of slashes might be due to the settings of **magic_quotes_gpc**, which is already removed in newer versions of PHP, but you can check your settings in **phpinfo();**

Comment: I agree you don't want to store the results of htmlspecialchars and nl2br.

Answer (score 0):

It may probably be because you have magic quotes on : magic_quotes_gpc
If that is the case you can disable it using [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)